# Consulta SQL que de como resultado las preguntas se hayan respondido 4 veces seguidas bien

Tags: mysql, sql

Quería conseguir que una consulta me devuelva como resultado los "numeroPregunta" según los siguientes parámetros:

Que cumpla:
-Que idUsuario = 1
-Que modalidadPreguntas = operarioDeServicios
-Que las últimas 4 veces que se haya respondido haya tenido como valor a respuestasCorrectas=1 (4 veces seguidas el valor 1 sin intercalar con 0)

Tabla:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

A lo que llego es a lo siguiente, pero me saca todas las que cumpliendo las concidiniones, tenga como valor de respuestasCorrectas=1, pero lo que necesito es que sea las que las últimas 4 respuestas haya tenido seguidas el valor 1. (Ya que en la lógica del programa, se entiende que si el usuario responde una pregunta 4 veces seguidas bien (valor 1), ha aprendido la respuesta y no interesa que salga de nuevo esa pregunta en el programa).

Esto a lo que he llegado, no es suficiente:

```
SELECT numeroPregunta 
FROM `respuestasTestUsuario` 
WHERE idUsuario=1 AND modalidadPreguntas ='operarioDeServicios' 
AND respuestasCorrectas=1
```

¡Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La clave está en  tu explicación de:

> 4 veces seguidas el valor 1 sin intercalar con 0

Y la función que hace eso de agrupar valores es GROUP_CONCAT (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat)

```
SELECT idUsuario, numeroPregunta, GROUP_CONCAT(correcta SEPARATOR '') as respuestas    
  FROM respuestasTestUsuario 
 WHERE idUsuario = 1 AND modalidadPreguntas ='operarioDeServicios'
 GROUP BY idUsuario, numeroPregunta
HAVING respuestasCorrectas  LIKE '%1111%'
 ORDER BY idUsuario, numeroPregunta, fechaRespuesta
```

O  si lo quieres mas resumido, solo con lo que pides en el enunciado:

```
SELECT numeroPregunta    
  FROM respuestasTestUsuario 
 WHERE idUsuario = 1 AND modalidadPreguntas ='operarioDeServicios'
 GROUP BY idUsuario, numeroPregunta
HAVING GROUP_CONCAT(correcta SEPARATOR '') LIKE '%1111%'
 ORDER BY idUsuario, numeroPregunta, fechaRespuesta
```